# Songbook \makeTitleIndex: Page number vs song number

Tags: page-numbering, indexing, songbook

I created a songbook using the `songbook` package.
As stated in the manual I added a `\makeTitleIndex` command to the preamble of my songbook. It creates a `.tIdx` file containing song titles and song numbers. However, I need the page numbers instead.

Is there a way to configure `\makeTitleIndex` to output page numbers (even though it is a parameterless command)? If not, what alternatives do I have? I'd like to use `makeindex` to convert the `.tIdx` to a `.tdx`.

Here an example: `songbook.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[chordbk]{songbook}

\begin{document}

    \makeTitleIndex

    \begin{song}{Song 1}{}{~}{}{}{} 
        song1
        \newpage
        song1 continued
    \end{song}


    \begin{song}{Song 2}{}{~}{}{}{}
        song2
    \end{song}

    \begin{song}{Song 3}{}{~}{}{}{}
        song3
    \end{song}

    \input{songbook.tdx}

\end{document}
```

Compile once. Then run:

```
makeindex -o songbook.tdx songbook.tIdx
```

Compile again. Note the index at end of PDF shows song numbers (not page numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `song` environment uses `\titleIndex{\theSongTitle}{\theSBSongCnt}` to make the index entry with song title and song counter value.

This can be patched with `\xpatchcmd` to change `\theSBSongCnt` to `\thepage`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[chordbk]{songbook}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\song}{%
  \titleIndex{\theSongTitle}{\theSBSongCnt}   %
}{%
  \titleIndex{\theSongTitle}{\thepage}   %
}{}{}


\begin{document}

    \makeTitleIndex

    \begin{song}{Song Foo}{}{~}{}{}{} 
        song1
        \newpage
        song1 continued
    \end{song}


    \begin{song}{Song Foobar}{}{~}{}{}{}
        song2
    \end{song}

    \begin{song}{Song Other Foobar}{}{~}{}{}{}
        song3
    \end{song}

    \input{songbook.tdx}

\end{document}
```

[image]