# Using different counter for Index (makeidx)

Tags: indexing, counters, xpatch, makeidx

I have a question similar to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294247/songbook-maketitleindex-page-number-vs-song-number/434127#434127): I'm using [makeidx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/makeidx) and I want the index to use a different counter than `\thepage`. My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeindex

\newcounter{NewCounter}

\setcounter{NewCounter}{5}

\makeatletter % the macro name contains @

\xpatchcmd{\@wrindex}{%
   \indexentry{#2}{\thepage}%
   }{%
   \indexentry{#2}{\NewCounter}%
   }
  {}{}% <success> and <failure> code not needed

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\stepcounter{NewCounter}\chapter{Test}\index{Test}
\arabic{NewCounter}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

So, unfortunately after compilation with `lualatex` and `makeindex`
 the entry "Test" has the pagenumber (1) instead of the NewCounter (6) in the index. Any help with the usage of `xpatchcmd`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to do it with `imakeidx`. For all who are interested:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\newcounter{NewCounter}

\setcounter{NewCounter}{5}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Index}[1]{\imki@wrindexentry{MyIndex}{#1}{\theNewCounter}}
\makeatother

\makeindex[name=MyIndex]

\begin{document}

\stepcounter{NewCounter}\chapter{Test}\Index{Test}
\arabic{NewCounter}

\printindex[MyIndex]

\end{document}
```

I defined an own index command `\Index`. The idea is pretty much given in the documentation of `imakeidx` p. 15.

Comment: Is very important to add an image of your work. +1 for you.