# Make index entries refer to a counter and not page numbers

Tags: macros, formatting, counters, makeindex

For a given work, I have a continuous numerotation throughout all the document using a counter.
I need the index entries refer to the paragraph numbers and not to the pages. This is the same issue than [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63643/make-index-entries-refer-to-number-selected-paragraphs), except I am not using `memoir` but `book`. Unfortunately, the solution presented does not work anymore switching from one document class to an other.

I have been looking at [this other thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20894/make-index-entries-refer-to-something-other-than-the-page-numbers). The solution looks really good, except it displays the counter's title instead of the counter's number.

Here is the code :

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{raphink.ist}
delim_0 ""
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{subpara}
\newcommand\numsubpara[1]{%
  \stepcounter{subpara}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname cursec\thesubpara\endcsname{#1}%
  \thesubpara. \textbf{#1}}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-s raphink]

\makeatletter
\let\@Index\@index
\patchcmd{\@Index}{\@wrindex}{\@Wrindex}{}{}
\let\@Wrindex\@wrindex
\patchcmd{\@Wrindex}{\thepage}{\thesubpara}{}{}
\let\xIndex\index
\patchcmd{\xIndex}{\@index}{\@Index}{}{}
\patchcmd{\xIndex}{\@index}{\@Index}{}{}
\let\protected@iwrite\protected@write
\patchcmd{\protected@iwrite}{\write}{\immediate\write}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@Wrindex}{\protected@write}{\protected@iwrite}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\Index}[1]{\xIndex{#1|transform}}
\newcommand{\transform}[1]{\forcsvlist\decodesec{#1}}
\newcommand{\decodesec}[1]{, \csname cursec#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test1}

\numsubpara{title1}

\Index{Test}

\chapter{Test2}

\numsubpara{title2}
\Index{Test}


\printindex

\end{document}
```

And the result :

[image]

If I have well understood, I would have to switch this :

```latex
\newcommand\numsubpara[1]{%
  \stepcounter{subpara}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname cursec\thesubpara\endcsname{#1}%
  \thesubpara. \textbf{#1}}
```

For that :

```latex
\newcommand\numsubpara[1]{%
  \stepcounter{subpara}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname cursec\thesubpara\endcsname{\thesubpara}%
  \thesubpara. \textbf{#1}}
```

But when I do this, I get this result :

[image]

Instead of "Test, 1,2".

Does anyone know how to have the index entries refer to the paragraph numbers and not to the pages ?

Comment: Why not try using `memoir` as it encompasses all that `book` does, and much more? Just replace `book` with `memoir` and perhaps change some of the options in your `\documentclass` command.

Comment: Hello @PeterWilson ! It is a solution indeed... but I have worked a lot on this template, and I would mean doing again a lot of other stuff...

Comment: @PeterWilson :  I have checked using ```memoir``` : a lot of different formatting do not work anymore. Here are some examples : I have used \usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec} to format \part title in my toc, doesn't work anymore; I have used \usepackage[cam,width=17.5truecm,height=25.54truecm,center,dvips,noinfo]{crop}
for printing marks, doesn't work anymore; \setstretch{1.1}; etc... A solution working with ```book``` would be really appreciated ! Thanks :)

Comment: I have not looked at it in uttermost detail but it seems to me that `\thesubpara` always refers to the very last value the counter takes. If you make a test with 4 indexed `subparas` rather than two in your examples, you always get values of 4, indicating that `\thesubpara` value in your index refers to the variable at its 'last state' in the document, not at the value it had in the place where it was set (which is what you want to get) - so it does not refer to the pages in you current example. If that's what you wanted to know (not sure)

Comment: @SLang, I didn't know ```\thesubpara``` was working this way, thank you very much. It explains why it is not working... Do you have any idea how to build something working? By the way, I have tried making a test with 4 indexed ```subpara```, and strangely it displays nothing..

Comment: with your current config, you apparently can only have the same Index-Tag max. twice, it works if you switch it out after than like `\Index{Bla}` - for example, if you add ```\newpage  bla \newpage bla 

\chapter{Test3}

\numsubpara{title3}
\Index{Bla}

\chapter{Test4}

\numsubpara{title4}
\Index{Bla}
``` to your document, you can see that even with the `\newpage`s, you still get the value 4, not 5 which is the current latest page

Comment: @SLang I have tried what you suggested, and you are right I get 4. Does it mean the issue is even more complicated?

Comment: Looked at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434129/using-different-counter-for-index-makeidx?rq=1) yet? Add ```\newcounter{NewCounter}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Indextest}[1]{\imki@wrindexentry{MyIndex}{#1}{\theNewCounter}}
\makeatother
\makeindex[name=MyIndex]``` before `\begin{document}` and this after your `\printindex`: ```\stepcounter{NewCounter}\chapter{xx}\Indextest{xx}
\arabic{NewCounter}

\stepcounter{NewCounter}\chapter{xx}\Indextest{xx}
\arabic{NewCounter}

\printindex[MyIndex]``` - seems to be working to me (although not sure if it's the desired behaviour)

Comment: It almost works perfectly ! Thank you so much !
I say almost because a strange vertical line has appeared between the two columns of my index. Any idea why ? I have used makeindex option ```columns``` : ```\makeindex[name=MyIndex, columns=2, options= -s tablealphab.ist]```

Comment: Edit : forget about my last comment, it was my mistake. Thanks again !

Comment: I added the solution as an answer ;) would be happy to get an upvote ;)

Comment: @Guliup Fair enough. `memoir` provides its own methods for the packages you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Understanding the value outputted by `\thesubpara`

In your example, `\thesubpara` always refers to the very last value the counter takes. If you make a test with 4 indexed `\subpara`s rather than two in your examples, you always get values of 4, indicating that `\thesubpara` value in your index refers to the variable at its 'last state' in the document, not at the value it had in the place where it was set (which is what you want to get) - so it does not refer to the pages in your current example (which, it seems, is what you thought initially).

### By the way

With your current config, you can only have the same `\Index` tag max. twice, so it only works if you switch it out after that, like like `\Index{Bla}` - for example, if you add

```
\newpage bla \newpage bla 

\chapter{Test3} 
\numsubpara{title3} 
\Index{Bla} 

\chapter{Test4} 
\numsubpara{title4} 
\Index{Bla}
```

to your document, you can see that even with the `\newpage`s, you still get the value 4, not 6 which is the current last page.

## A quick fix solution

Have you looked at [this (question: Using different counter for Index (makeidx))](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434129/using-different-counter-for-index-makeidx?rq=1) yet? It seems to provide the wanted output. Add:

```
\newcounter{NewCounter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Indextest}[1]{\imki@wrindexentry{MyIndex}{#1}{\theNewCounter}}
\makeatother

\makeindex[name=MyIndex]
```

before `\begin{document}` and this after the `\printindex` of your current example, add (for testing):

```
\stepcounter{NewCounter}\chapter{Test}\Indextest{Test}
\arabic{NewCounter}

\stepcounter{NewCounter}\chapter{Test}\Indextest{Test}
\arabic{NewCounter}

\newpage 

\stepcounter{NewCounter}\chapter{Test}\Indextest{blurb}
\arabic{NewCounter}

\stepcounter{NewCounter}\chapter{Test}\Indextest{Test}
\arabic{NewCounter}

\printindex[MyIndex]
```

This should produce the desired behaviour, like so:

[image: the resulting output]